# wrong encoding detection PHP

Tags: php, encoding

i have some files that with this way

```
$enclist = mb_list_encodings();
$encode = mb_detect_encoding($str, $enclist);
```

the detected encoding of them is ISO-8859-1, but when i want convert them to utf-8 by iconv , the converted string is wrong and is not human readable , I am using this way to convert

```
        $str = iconv($encode, 'UTF-8', $str);
```

so i guess the detected encoding is wrong , and then i tried this :

```
foreach ($enclist as $item) {
    $rowStr = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', $item);
    echo $item .'<br />';
    echo substr($rowStr, 0, 100) .'<br />';
}
```

but none of the encoded lines is not the correct text (file can be readed correctly in my windows and notepad++ show ANSI for encoding)

Comment: `show ANSI for encoding` may convert the file into utf8 - i mean the php schript file, not the output file if you parse it to a file

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions sorry , what you means ?

Comment: The encoding of the PHP scriptfile is also important, bcause you can write plain text into it (HTML) and this texts can have äöü utf8 chars, so the php file itself must have the right encoding to work as expected

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions , this script work for must of files , and just for some files it have problem , also output is writing in file , but also i checked  the file and its UTF-8

Comment: If you have some examples update your question.

Comment: Dont forget setting this right `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');` before using iconv

Comment: ---- killed, wrong commend

Comment: Ref Links : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-list-encodings.php